# How can you find out the position and rotation of an object in relationship to its parent?

Tags: geometry-nodes

When you add an Object Info node for an object that is the child of another object the location and rotation outputs are its world coordinate position and rotation. I would like to find out the location and rotation of an object in its local coordinates. In other words, as if the parent object was at the center of the world and not rotated at all. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Using **Relative** *Location/Rotation* from *Object Info* node seems to be value you are looking for ...

[image]

*Cube* at World origin is *Parent*, *Cube.001* is a *Child* ... When you move Child object values at *Spread Sheet* are changing. When you move by Parent object - values are kept.

In other words - *Location* values of *Object Info* node set to *Relative* gives you child location like parent object is at child's 0/0/0 local world origin.

[image]

Comment: Also known as *Local* transforms

Comment: Thanks @validu. But that is not quite what I would like to find out. For example in this image you can see that if I create a new object and put your node setup in it (bottom image), the information I get is the child cube's world position and rotation. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiE01B39ctoQhOpA9Wdx5R7yhrP7Uw?e=ZSfVdU. I have tried just subtracting the position and rotation of the parent from the child. But apparently its more complicated than that. I have been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: I think I didn't get your point. Probably add some sketch (drawing) explaining what position (or distance) are you aiming to calculate. Like now it does what I understood you asked for. When I add Plane with GN, the Cube.001 (child) position is calculated from Plane position = means Plane is taken into account as World Origin.